# What zodiac system is used in Jewish horoscopes - sidereal or tropical?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, astrology

The zodiac systems are repeatedly discussed in various Kabbalistic treatises, including the Sefer Yetzirah and the Zohar. However, what is the zodiac system there: tropical or sidereal?

Tropical - the signs of the zodiac are counted from the point of the vernal equinox.

Sidereal - the signs of the zodiac coincide with the zodiac constellations.

Comment: I doubt anyone considered the difference till recently.

Comment: THere's no distinctive Jewish astrological tradition. IIRC, rabbis mention basic astronomic terms (this constellation's rising at that hour) but I don't recall them analyzing personal charts. It is reasonable to speculate that in non-religious matters rabbis followed their surrounding cultures (Babylon, Greece, Rome, etc).